# SAP ABAP Listen on Port

Tags: http, sapui5, abap

I have created a RFC Connection (SM59) to an external HTTP Server. I can now send a HTTP POST from SAP to this server and get a response of it. But in some cases the web server has to send a request to SAP.

How can I let SAP listen on a specific port and call an event in case of an request from the web server?

Comment: SAP listens to HTTP calls starting by the customizing defined in the transaction code `SICF`. There are also websockets called ABAP Push Channels. Your question is quite vague, maybe you can complete it so that to obtain a more precise answer?

Comment: I have created a class where I create an object from the class cl_http_client and send a POST with data to a webserver. This function works perfectly with the created RFC destination in SM59. But I want to send data from the webserver to SAP where the websever sends a POST and the SAP server should react to it.

Comment: My previous comment/answer still applies. If you want something really basic, use `SICF` to create an ICF service and assign a handler class which implements `IF_HTTP_EXTENSION`. There are lots of examples in the web.

Comment: It worked with SICF and a handler class.

Comment: @lbGaunt if it works, please post your solution as answer so it will useful for others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for this problem was to create a service in transaction SICF. The created service is called by the external web server over the created URL. The incoming events will be handled by a handler class, which i have linked with the service in SICF.